# What are the address input pins used for in ds1621?

Tags: i2c, pinout

I just bought a ds1621 temperature sensor and started reading its [datasheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1621.pdf).
I found out that it have 3 pins (A0,A1,A2) which as specified in the datasheet are chip address input.

Can somebody explain to me  further the interest of having those pins ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the data sheet says: -

> SLAVE ADDRESS A control byte is the first byte received following the
>   START condition from the master device. The control byte consists of a
>   4-bit control code; for the DS1621, this is set as 1001 binary for
>   read and write operations. The next 3 bits of the control byte are the
>   device select bits (A2, A1, A0). They are used by the master device to
>   select which of eight devices are to be accessed. These bits are in
>   effect the 3 least significant bits of the slave address. The last bit
>   of the control byte (R/W) defines the operation to be performed. When
>   set to a “1” a read operation is selected, when set to a “0” a write
>   operation is selected. Following the START condition the DS1621
>   monitors the SDA bus checking the device type identifier being
>   transmitted. Upon receiving the 1001 code and appropriate device
>   select bits, the slave device outputs an acknowledge signal on the SDA
>   line.

Basically, if you have several DS1621 devices, you can set the hardware address for each and exclusively read up to 8 devices. The one below is set to have address 000: -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A little addition to @[Andy aka](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/20218/andy-aka) 's answer.

Your device uses **I<sup>2</sup>C**, or often called **2-wire** serial communication.
In this communication protocol the master selects a slave by sending its address to the bus, and the specific slave identifies itself by this address.

Here is a picture of **I<sup>2</sup>C**'s message frame.

[image: I2C message frame]

As you can see there is a `Slave Address` field which is 7 bit long. This is the address you set as it is described in the datasheet and in @[Andy aka](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/20218/andy-aka) 's answer. The first (from MSB) 4 bit are fixed the last 3 could be set with (A0,A1,A2) pins.